# Provide link of a page in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have a database of questions which are viewed in localhost:8000/questions/{id}. I have created a chatbot in the existing laravel project. Now, I want to provide the user with the link of the question. 
For example, if I want the link to a question of id=55, then the bot has to reply me with the link localhost:8000/questions/55. 
How do I do that?

web.php

```
Route::resources([ 'questions' => 'QuestionController', ]); 
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/botman', 'BotManController@handle');
```

QuestionController.php

```
public function show(Question $question) { 
    return view('question')->with('question', $question); 
}
```

botman.php

```
use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan; 
use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory; 
use BotMan\BotMan\Cache\DoctrineCache; 
use BotMan\BotMan\Drivers\DriverManager; 
use App\Conversations\StartConversation; 

DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Web\WebDriver::class); 
$cachedriver = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\PhpFileCache('cache'); 
BotManFactory::create(config('botman', new 
DoctrineCache($cachedriver))); 
$botman = app('botman'); 
$botman->hears('Hello|Hi', 
       function($bot) { 
          $bot->typesAndWaits(1); 
          $bot->startConversation(new StartConversation); 
       }
);
```

BotManController.php

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan; 
use BotMan\BotMan\BotManFactory;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations;
use App\Conversations\StartConversation; 

class BotManController extends Controller { 
    public function handle() { 
        $botman = app('botman'); 
        $botman->listen(); 
    } 
    public function startConversation(Botman $bot) { 
        $bot->startConversation(new StartConversation()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: So the question that i will be giving to the chatbot will be saved in $answer.
I had to search for the question in the database and I did.
Now, i want the link to that question.
The "what is apple?" was an example that I was giving so it would be easier to understand.

Comment: are you getting all those questions up to 'what is apple' question? I mean as I know, each conversation should implement the run method of the abstract *Conversation*  class, but your conversations do not as I see

Comment: they are. I didn't have enough space, so i didn't include them in the comment.
See the part where I did the whole DB::table command. They are working perfectly fine. When i display the variable, it shows the question that i was searching for. But the part where .route('questions.show'), that is not working. It isn't displaying anything

Comment: @NaveenaKurma edit your question and put the code in the question, not the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first we get all the ids from the questions table:

```
$questions   = DB::table('questions')->select('id')->where('body', 'like', '%' . $answer . '%')->get();
```

$ids here is a collection of id so for each id we must create a link:

```
$links = array();
foreach($questions as $question){
     $links[] = route('questions.show', ['id' => $question->id]);
}
```

so now we have all links needed to return as answer, finish it using `$this->say`... as you wish

---

you may want to return the first link not all links then get the first id from the database and create link using it:

```
$question = DB::table('questions')->select('id')->where('body', 'like', '%' . $answer . '%')->first()
$link = route('questions.show', ['id' => $question->id]);
```

then return the answer using `$this->say`

I hope this helps

Comment: is it possible to convert the ids into an array, like typecasting it?

Comment: yes you can by calling *toArray* method, and yes, please check my updated answer. please post any error you face so we can help.

Comment: i'm not getting any error. I'm just not getting any output. so I thought of converting the $id to an integer and then call it in the route function

Comment: please post the output of `dd($question);` or `dd($questions);` based on number of answers you choose

Comment: as it is a chatbot, i don't think dd() won't work. but i'll try

Comment: when i display what's in the $questions, it shows [{"id":"155"}]

Comment: Since it is a database record, i tried to convert it into an associative array using collect($questions)->toArray(); When i access the id as $questions['id'], it isn't working.

Comment: `$questions` is a collection, you can't access the `id` field like this `$questions['id']`, because it has many object! so you need to select one element then access its id, in your example it's `$questions[0]->id`

Comment: However, I had another doubt. It is a small one though. each user has 18 questions in their homepage and i inserted paginate(6), so each page has 6 questions. Now, when i want to add the chat widget, it is disabling the pagination. Would you happen to know where i would have to insert the script for widget?